# LDAP add telephone number

Tags: shell

Hi how do I add telephone number using ldap ? I tried this but it doesn't work

```
ldapadd -x -D "cn=admin,dc=example,dc=com, TelephoneNumber=071198" -w password -H ldap:// -f      newgroups.ldif
```

Comment: `ldapmodify -a` (which is `ldapadd`) takes entry information from `stdin` or from a file with the `-f` option. The command above attempts to read the new telephone number from `newgroups.ldif` which does not seem like what you want.

Comment: yes, so how can I modify this to add the information, I'm kind of lost

Comment: OK, if you have the new information you are attempting to add in `newgroups.ldif`, then your command makes more sense, Take a look at [YoLinux LDAP Tutorial](http://www.yolinux.com/TUTORIALS/LinuxTutorialLDAP-BindPW.html) for a walkthrough.